# Reduction of a type of elliptic integral to Legendre normal form

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, elliptic-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

---

Define the set $D$ to be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ specified as follows:

$$D:=\{\left(a,b,c,d,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{5}\mid c>0\land z\ge a\land z>d\}.$$

For each $\left(a,b,c,d,z\right)\in D$, the improper integral $\int_{z}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(x-d\right)\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)\left[\left(x-b\right)^{2}+c^{2}\right]}}$ can be shown to converge using the standard comparison test. Thus, the function $\mathcal{E}:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is well-defined via the elliptic integral representation

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b,c,d,z\right)}
&:=\int_{z}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(x-d\right)\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)\left[\left(x-b\right)^{2}+c^{2}\right]}}.\\
\end{align}$$

(Note: I shall adopt the same convention as [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2) for defining the elliptic integrals of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd kind.)

My initial goal was to obtain a general expression for the elliptic integral $\mathcal{E}$ reduced to Legendre normal form using the substitution

$$\frac{2\sqrt{A\left(x-a\right)}}{x-a+A}=t;~~~\small{A:=\sqrt{\left(a-b\right)^{2}+c^{2}}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}},$$

but proceeding this way seems to require a good bit of casework. Some of the casework can be eliminated by adding the assumptions $a<d\land a+A<z$, which is what I'm primarily interested in. This seems to result in elliptic integrals of the third kind having characteristic greater than unity.

> **Question:** Is there an alternative way to reduce $\mathcal{E}$ to Legendre's three elliptic integrals such all elliptic integral variables are in their normal ranges, i.e., $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}\land0<\kappa<1\land0<n<1$?

---

Comment: +1. This is a GREAT question. If there's no answers I might put a bounty. I looked at your profile and saw you followed a proposal for a Materials Modeling Stack Exchange. If you don't mind another attempt at a Materials proposal, would you be so kind to commit to this? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0 It started slow but lately it's been booming with 5 commitments/day and very soon it will reach 200.